# How to visualize the content of Graphics variable in Visual Studio 2010 during debug?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, debuggervisualizer

I am working on a rendering engine for my application and need to visualize the Graphics object during the debug session.
I looked at Image Visualizers for VS2010, like [this](http://imagedebugvisualizer.codeplex.com/) or [this](http://victorhurdugaci.com/projects/vsimagevisualizer/), but they visualize only the Image objects, whereas I need the Graphics. What could be a solution here?

Regards,
Alexander.

Comment: Are you talking about something like the one discussed here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/GraphicDebuggerVisualizer.aspx?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to adapt this visualizer for VS2010, it seems not to work with VS2010 at the moment.

Comment: I finally got it running, thank you for drawing my attention to this CodeProject page!

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer below. You can accept your own answers and it provides better question/answer separation. It will also have the beneficial effect of showing that the question has been answered and completed.

Comment: @JYelton: I had to wait for some time to be able to post answer to my own question, so I first added it to the question. Now, following your advice, I editted it to follow the Q&A pattern. Thank you for you suggestion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured it out on my own.

To enable the visualisation of `Graphics` variables in VS2010 do the following:

1. Download the Graphics Debugger Visualizer from [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/GraphicDebuggerVisualizer.aspx) Code Project page (use the pre-compiled DLL version).
2. Extract the DLL to the location where you have full rights.
3. Right-click the DLL and press "Unblock" button on the first tab, in the right bottom corner. Click "Apply" and then "OK" to close the Properties Window.
4. Copy the DLL to the following location:

   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers`

   -or-

   `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers`
     depending upon your system architecture.
5. You don't have to restart VS2010, just run a debugging session and you'll see a small magnifying glass sign just to the left of the variable type name when you hover with you mouse cursor over your variable. Click this sign and you'll see the content of your Graphics object opened in a new window.
6. Enjoy!

Comment: Unfortunately this dll doesn't work with newer versions of the Visual Studio. (VS2015 throws an exception "Operation is not supported")